# lisp iterate through list

Tags: scheme, lisp, gimp, script-fu

I just started GIMP script-fu scripting yesterday for a script I need but I have no idea how automate the adding of the layers in the local variables and calling the function for adding the layers to the image. I tried iterating over lists but failed gracefully. Can someone push me in the right direction?

```
(define (script-fu-gifslot inText inFont inFontSize inTextColor)
    (let*
        ((theImageWidth  700) ; define our local variables
         (theImageHeight 100) ; create a new image:
         (theImage)
         (layerX)
         (inOffset)
         (theImage (car (gimp-image-new theImageWidth theImageHeight RGB)))
         (theText)             ;a declaration for the text

         (theLayer (car (gimp-layer-new theImage theImageWidth theImageHeight RGB-IMAGE "layer 1" 100 NORMAL)))
         (theLayer2 (car (gimp-layer-new theImage theImageWidth theImageHeight RGB-IMAGE "layer 2" 100 NORMAL)))
         (theLayer3 (car (gimp-layer-new theImage theImageWidth theImageHeight RGB-IMAGE "layer 3" 100 NORMAL)))
         (theLayer4 (car (gimp-layer-new theImage theImageWidth theImageHeight RGB-IMAGE "layer 4" 100 NORMAL))))

      (define (yannis-add-new-layer layerX inOffset)
          (gimp-image-add-layer theImage layerX 0)
        (gimp-context-set-background '(255 255 255))
        (gimp-context-set-foreground inTextColor)
        (gimp-drawable-fill layerX BACKGROUND-FILL)

        (set! theText (car (gimp-text-fontname theImage layerX 0 0 inText 0 TRUE inFontSize PIXELS "Sans")))
        (set! theImageHeight  (car (gimp-drawable-height theText)))

        (gimp-layer-resize layerX theImageWidth theImageHeight 0 0)
        (gimp-layer-set-offsets theText 0 (- 0 inOffset)))
      (yannis-add-new-layer theLayer 0)
      (yannis-add-new-layer theLayer2 10)
      (yannis-add-new-layer theLayer3 20)
      (yannis-add-new-layer theLayer4 30)
      (gimp-display-new theImage)
      (list theImage layerX theText)))

(script-fu-register 
 "script-fu-gifslot"
 "_GGGIF WORD Slotmachine..."
 "Creates an image with a user specified text string."
 "Yannis De Cleene <yannisdcl@gmail.com>"
 "Yannis De Cleene"
 "July, 2014"
 ""
 SF-TEXT       "Text"                "PASTE\nMULTILINE TEXT\nIN HERE"
 SF-FONT       "Font"                "Sans"
 SF-ADJUSTMENT "Font size (pixels)"  '(100 2 1000 1 10 0 1)
 SF-COLOR      "Color"               '(0 0 0))

(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-gifslot" "<Image>/File/Create")
```

Comment: Another option, unless you are already familiar with scheme/lisp is to use the Python bindings instead, for automating GIMP. The language gets a lot less in your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `map` or `for-each` or `do`.

If you want to add 1 to a list you could use `(map 1+ '(1 2 3))`. Or if you want to define the function on the fly, use lambda: `(map (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) '(1 2 3))`

If you want a more imperative style use do. You can read about it [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/guile/guile_294.html#IDX1068).

You can search for functions (and other bound symbols) using the function `apropos`. e.j. `(apropos "for")` (Apparently not in gimp to my surpise)

However I sense your problem is larger than just iterate over a list. For example does it make sense to define the function over the let? why are you not explicitly passing the image to the add-new-layer-function?

To make your code more readable I would drop the 'the', use '-' instead of camelCase and don't leave one parentesis in each line. it hurts readability. I can see however it is not your fault as that style is used in the gimp's tutorial. e.j. theImage becomes image and TheLayer1 becomes layer-1.

If you want to learn more about scheme you should download racket and read how to design programs which is a good introduction to programming.